# Exercise of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The ratio of boys to girls at birth in India is quite high at $1.09 : 1$. What proportion of Indian families with exactly $6$ children will have at least 3 boys? (Ignore the probability of multiple births).

#### My attempt:

probability of boys ,$p=\frac{1.09}{1.09+1}=0.52 $

total children, $n=6$

P(at least 3 boys)$=\sum_{x=3}^{6}\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}=0.9262$

But it has been noticed as incorrect answer ?

Where have i mistaken ?

Comment: Don't know. The $p$ is roughly right, but it is better not to round. The formula for the probability of at least $3$ boys is correct. Mistake is in evaluation.

Comment: With p = 0.5215311, I got: 
3 0.310764766
4 0.254050196
5 0.110765885
6 0.020122469
 0.695703316

Answer (score 0):

With p = 0.5215311, I got:

X=3 0.310764766

X=4 0.254050196

X=5 0.110765885

X=6 0.020122469

For a total of 0.695703316